# Will The Thread Stop in This Promise Computation

Tags: scala

I want to confirm my understanding of the promise in Scala. Given the below code:

```scala
    val promise = Promise[Option[Boolean]]

    foo().value.onComplete {
      case Failure(exception) => promise.success(None)
      case Success(value) =>
        value match {
          case Left(a)  => promise.success(None)
          case Right(b) => promise.success(Some(b))
        }
    }
    promise.future
```

Will the thread that runs through this statement halt until `foo` is completed or does it continue through it immediately and not wait for the callback?

Comment: What does `foo()` return?

Comment: @Thilo it doesn't matter

Comment: It matters, because then we can know what `.value` is and what `.onComplete` does.

Comment: It's EitherT[Future, Error, Boolean] - but it doesn't matter. It's a future computation.

Answer (score 1):

`Future#onComplete` registers a handler to be run when the Future completes.

It does not wait for that completion to happen.

If the Future is already completed, the handler will be run immediately or scheduled asynchronously, depending on the implicit ExecutionContext.

Comment: OK so I was thinking about it incorrectly. When foo completes then it will execute the code inside the onComplete block but the main thread will pass through and carry on with other stuff